# Sockets creation from a named tuple issue

Tags: python, sockets

Am creating a python server socket from the return value os `socket.getaddrinfo` which returns a sequence of 5-tuple   `(family, socktype, proto, canonname, sockaddr)`
This is my code.

```
 import socket
 import collections

sock_info_tuple = namedtuple('sock_info_tuple', 'family type proto  cannon sockaddr_tuple')
socket_info =   sock_info_tuple._make(socket.getaddrinfo('127.0.0.1',80,socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM,socket.IPPROTO_TCP))

TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-90-b04233a8e38d> in <module>()
  5 #get the socket info
  6 sock_info_tuple = namedtuple('sock_info_tuple', 'family type proto cannon sockaddr_tuple')
----> 7 socket_info =  sock_info_tuple._make(socket.getaddrinfo('127.0.0.1',80,socket.AF_INET,socket     .SOCK_STREAM,socket.IPPROTO_TCP))
  8 
  9 #create the server scket and pass the arguments

<string> in _make(cls, iterable, new, len)

TypeError: Expected 5 arguments, got 1
```

so whats probably the problem and yet the socket.getaddrinfo returns the tuple

Answer (score 1):

If `socket.getaddrinfo` returns `(family, socktype, proto, canonname, sockaddr)` as tuple, You should use `*` to unpack this tuple.

```
socket_info = sock_info_tuple._make(*socket.getaddrinfo('127.0.0.1',80,socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM,socket.IPPROTO_TCP))
```